# Why do not use pointer variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

I am a completely newbie in iOS app development.

I am following a tutorial, which has the following code snippet in the **BIDAppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.switchViewController = [[BIDSwitchViewController alloc]
                                 initWithNibName:@"SwitchView" bundle:nil];


    UIView *switchView = self.switchViewController.view;

     /**** WHY here do not use pointer variable? ****/
    CGRect switchViewFrame = switchView.frame; 

    switchViewFrame.origin.y+=[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    switchView.frame = switchViewFrame;
    self.window.rootViewController=self.switchViewController;
    ...
    ...
    return YES;
    }
```

I understand what does the above code do, generally, when app starts, it loads the view of a root controller(`switchViewController`) & make some view adjustment.

My question is, in the code why `CGRect switchViewFrame = switchView.frame;` does not use pointer variable like this way: `CGRect *switchViewFrame = switchView.frame;` ?

**===============Update==================**

Now, I realize the reason is that `CGRect` is a structure, not a objective-c class. 
then, Can I re-define the line of code to:

```
struct CGRect switchViewFrame, *sViewFrame; 
sViewFrame = switchView.frame;
```

Is above code identical to `CGRect switchViewFrame = switchView.frame;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CGRect` is a C structure, not an Objective-C object. `CGRect` is declared in `CGGeometry.h`, which is part of the Core Graphics framework, which has a C API.

Comment: Can I re-define the line of code to:  `struct CGRect switchViewFrame, *sViewFrame; sViewFrame = switchView.frame;`   ?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? Objective-C being a strict superset of C, you must be at ease with mixing C and Objective-C.

Comment: You would have to allocate memory for sViewFrame (and release it) and make sure that you copy the data content or you would have to assign the address of switchView.frame to sViewFrame. However, it does not work the way you suggest. Why would you want to do that? Or do you just ask out of curiosity - which is understandable and a matter of learning?

Comment: @Hermann Klecker thank you for your comment. I am just curious, yes, it is a matter of learning :)

Comment: Just typing random code will not help you learn that much.  Try to determine *why* you would write a line like that.  First, essentially, you should consider the difference between an object and a struct / primitive.  This requires understanding, in general, how program memory works (stack vs heap).  If you research those topics, I'm sure you will understand why this time you will not use a pointer.

Comment: Why do you want to modify it? Why do you want a pointer variable for the object's frame ?